# wordpress custom-style.css does not apply styles

Tags: css

I started making a new theme. I thought of adding Bootstrap. However, after adding bootstrap, the css file I created for the site is not functional. It ignores any code I've inserted into it. It prioritizes codes in Bootstrap. All files appear in the site header. upload successful. but bootstrap gives priority. Where am I doing wrong?

```
function load_stylesheets()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", array(), false, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'site-stil', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/site-stil.css", array(), false, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/bootstrap.min.css", array(), false, 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_stylesheets');
```

[image]

Comment: Bootstraps CSS selectors may have greater [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than yours. We'd need to see the actual code that isn't being applied.

Comment: And either way, you should change the order, so that you own stylesheet gets embedded _after_ bootstrap's, not before.

Comment: @CBroe Yeah. It happened when I changed the order. thank you. it couldn't be that simple. I am ashamed of myself. problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just swapped the lines. Fixed. Thanks @CBroe

```
function load_stylesheets()
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css", array(), false, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/bootstrap.min.css", array(), false, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'site-stil', get_template_directory_uri() . "/css/site-stil.css", array(), false, 'all' );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','load_stylesheets');
```